# Svmono Class - Numbered Paragraph (Section)

Tags: sections-paragraphs, sv-classes

Does anyone know how to set up the [svmono class](http://static.springer.com/sgw/documents/125161/application/zip/svmono.zip) in order to get the paragraph sections numbered as well? The default setting is without numbering. See MWE:

```
% !TEX TS-program = pdflatex
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% ORIGINAL SPRINGER VORLAGE

\documentclass{svmono}

\begin{document}
   \chapter{Chapter}
   \section{Section}
   \subsection{Subsection}
   \subsubsection{SubSubsection}
   \paragraph{Paragraph}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not going to download a class file that I will never use. However if `svmono` is like the standard classes then put

```
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{4}
```

in your preamble and `\paragraph` should be numbered. For numbering `\subparagraph` s change the `4` to `5`.